# Вывод значения при выборе двух id из списков

Tags: javascript, jquery

Только начинаю осваивать js и jquerry,много гуглил, плохо понятно.
Как установить id элемента, если есть 2 списка, т.е. в зависимости от выбора в этих списках, id элемента бы менялся, для того чтобы вывести уже значение по этому id.

```html
<select id="oboroti" name="Oboroti_v_minyty" class="form-select">
                        <option value="1">28 оборотов в минуту</option>
                        <option value="2">47 оборотов в минуту</option>
                        <option value="3">70 оборотов в минуту</option>
      <option value="4">140 оборотов в минуту</option>
</select>
<select id="moshnost" name="Moshnost" class="form-select">
                        <option value="5">Мощность 0,12 кВт</option>
                        <option value="6">Мощность 0,15 кВт</option>
                        <option value="7">Мощность 0,18 кВт</option>
                        <option value="8">Мощность 0,20 кВт</option>
</select>
```

Comment: `id` какого элемента? И каким образом он должен меняться? Нужно немного больше информации

Comment: Смотрите, допустим, я выбрал в первом списке - option value="3" , во втором - option value="7", мне нужно вывести div блок. Этот div блок отображается, только если выбраны эти самые опции в списках. Т.е. если значение 3 и 7, то вывести 37 и так далее. Если значение в одном из списков меняется, то и соответственно меняется информация в div'е.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если я верно понял, то нужно просто повесить обработчик на изменения значений в select-списках и формировать `id` в зависимости от выбранных значений

```js
function showElement() {
  // сначала прячем все ответы
  $(".answers div").hide();
  
  // получаем текущие значения первого и второго списка
  var selectOne = $('#oboroti').val();
  var selectTwo = $('#moshnost').val();
  
  // формируем id div-блока
  var id = '#a' + selectOne + '-' + selectTwo
   
  // если значения не нулевые, то показываем блок с нужным id
  if (selectOne && selectTwo) {
    $(".answers").find(id).show();
  }
}

//при изменении значений в select будет вызываться showElement
$('#moshnost, #oboroti').change(showElement);

showElement();
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="oboroti" name="Oboroti_v_minyty" class="form-select">
  <option value="1">28 оборотов в минуту</option>
  <option value="2">47 оборотов в минуту</option>
  <option value="3">70 оборотов в минуту</option>
  <option value="4">140 оборотов в минуту</option>
</select>
<select id="moshnost" name="Moshnost" class="form-select">
  <option value="5">Мощность 0,12 кВт</option>
  <option value="6">Мощность 0,15 кВт</option>
  <option value="7">Мощность 0,18 кВт</option>
  <option value="8">Мощность 0,20 кВт</option>
</select>

<div class="answers">
  <div id="a1-5">a1-5</div>
  <div id="a2-5">a2-5</div>
  <div id="a3-7">a3-7</div>
</div>
```

Если нужно выводить (`$('#oboroti').val() + $('#moshnost').val()`) и менять значение в одном `div`, то можно немного подправить функцию:

```
// <div class="answers"></div>
function showElement() {
  // отчищаем ответ
  $(".answers").text();

  // получаем текущие значения первого и второго списка
  var selectOne = $('#oboroti').val();
  var selectTwo = $('#moshnost').val();

  // формируем текст div-блока
  var id = selectOne + selectTwo;
  $(".answers").text(id);
}
```

Comment: Да, что-то такое, спасибо!